# Why is nothing showing up when i use this code?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            //
            string filesizer;
            //
            filesizer = r.Next(0, 100).ToString();


            string yourfile = textBox1.Text;
            string myfile = filesizer;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Your File Size");
            }


            if (yourfile.Length < myfile.Length)

            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ha ha your File smol");
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have big File");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

when i run this code, nothing happens. no error no messagebox, nothing. even when i have it as empty it says nothing. do i have something messed up here? is something i have put on my form broken? i know the code is not clean and hard to read but it is what it is. ill fix it in a bit.

Comment: Your code isn't running at all. The `if`/`else` will always call one `MessageBox.Show` so your event isn't being handled.

Comment: Did you write all the code - including the function header `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`, or you double-clicked `button1` and then added the code?

Comment: @JoshPart i went and clicked viewcode over button one

Comment: @Enigmativity How would i go about fixing this?

Comment: `String.Length` is not going to use the value in the string.  `"25"` will not be `25` because you are telling it to use the *length* of the string.  As such you ought to handle the case where the string are both the same length such as `"11"` and `"99"`

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp so instead of using String.Length, how do i compare the size of it. as in 32 < 100. i cant use ```yourfile < myfile```, it gives me a error

Comment: Why are you using strings to compare numbers? Why not use a numeric type, like `int`?

Comment: @RufusL thats prob a better idea

Comment: Check your `button1` events and make sure `button1_Click` is set as the `Click` event.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that *"nothing happens. no error no messagebox, nothing."*, then it's likely that you haven't hooked up the button's `Click` event to your event handler. To do this, open the form designer, select the button, then in the Properties window click the lightning-bolt icon (to see the events) and select your event handler for the `Click` event:

[image]

Alternatively, you can do this in code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.button1.Click += button1_Click;
}
```

---

Regarding the code itself, perhaps a better way to do this is to compare numeric values using a numeric type, like `int` or `double` rather than `string`.

One way to do this is to use `int.TryParse` to get the value from the textbox as an integer. This method takes in a string and has an `out` parameter that it will set to the converted value if it's successful. It also returns a `bool` indicating success, so we can use that as an `if` condition:

```
// Random only needs to be created once at the class level
private Random r = new Random();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do our validation first and exit early if there's invalid input
    // Use int.TryParse to determine if the value is a number (and get the converted value)
    int userFileSize;
    if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out userFileSize))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Numeric File Size");
        return;
    }

    // Get a random file size
    int randomFileSize = r.Next(0, 100);

    if (userFileSize < randomFileSize)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ha ha your File smol. Mine is: " + randomFileSize);
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have big File! Mine is only: " + randomFileSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, but the error given is cannot simply convert string to int and operator < can not be applied to int and string

Comment: Oops, I copied your code and forgot to change `string` to `int` when assigning the random number. Please see updated code!

Comment: Nevermind! I got it!